# Custom PHP code in Rules differs from Devel's one

Tags: 6, rules, debugging

I'm facing an issue which is quite boring since the result displayed into Devel's PHP executer differs from the results of the Custom PHP code. What I want to do is sending private messages (thanks to privatemsg module) to certain users that I can't select with privatemsg Rules integration.

To send a new private_msg, we have to use the function "`privatemsg_new_thread($recipients, $subject, $body)`".

So I have to write a custom PHP code which is (I made it very simple) ; this one works in Devel but not in Rules.

```
$recipients = array(user_load(1));
$subject = 'hello';
$body = 'ok';
privatemsg_new_thread($recipients, $subject, $body);
```

When i write this ; it works with both modules

```
privatemsg_new_thread(array(user_load(1)), 'hello', 'ok');
```

Is there a problem with loading variables or sth ?
And i don't have any error log...

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not actually an answer to your question, but Privatemsg 6.x-2.x has built-in rules integration, with actions to send new messages and reply to existing ones. So, no custom PHP code required.

Comment: Hey ! Thank you for answer ! Indeed, I know that but the thing is that with the built-in rules integration, we are not that free to select the recipients of the mail ; this is what i wanted to do :-)

Comment: Sure you can! You can send a message to any user you want. You just need to add a load user action first, where you can specify a hardcoded uid or something token based.

Comment: Actually, I want to select all the users of a certain role ! I have finally suceeded by deleting and creating a new rule with the same PHP code ; I guess there must be a bug in there !

Comment: FYI: The 7.x versions of Privatemsg also have a "send to role" rules action, but this hasn't been backported yet to 6.x-2.x. However, Privatemsg 6.x-2.x does allow sending messages to roles, when using a recipient object like this: `$recipient = new stdClass(); $recipient->rid = $rid; $recipient->type = 'role';` (the privatemsg_roles module needs to be enabled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally suceeded by deleting and creating a new rule with the same PHP code ; I guess there must be a bug in there !